# Is a question about cutting plexiglass on a table saw off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Title pretty much says it all.  Would a question about cutting plexiglass on a table saw be off-topic for this site?  Is it better to post it at the DIY site?

### Update with background info

I'm building a router bit box.  I want to cut a piece of plexiglass to insert in a wooden frame which will be my see-through closing lid.

Comment: Now, it's part of a woodworking project, and one others might use.  Feel free to try it out.  It might be borderline, but having a question closed or moved to another stack is not a black mark on your record.

Answer (score 4):

While I might be tempted to answer it, I would have to say it really isn't on topic here.  But how it is asked might make a difference.  If it has to do with a woodworking project then you might get away with it.

Comment: About the only instance I could think of would be if it were as a table top or a panel for a terrarium or something. Even then I think it would be a stretch.

Comment: @bowlturner I'm not really trying to get away with.  I'm trying to see if people would find it useful as a question.

Comment: @MaximeMorin I think it would be a useful question, I just don't think it really matches with woodworking.  DIY might be a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Woodworking occasionally involves materials other than wood. People can ask about glue, fasteners, and hardware, none of which are wood. I can see how a question about cutting plexiglass isn't exactly on topic, but if it's in the context of cutting a piece of plexiglass to fit into a woodworking project, or even if it's not but such information would be useful to someone doing the same for a woodworking project, then it makes sense to leave it open.

Comment: I pose a similar question to you then. If I try to use carpenters glue to assemble plastic fruit in a bowl would you consider that on topic? It does use glue... There was a recent question about awning for a shutter that was closed. It _involves_ wood but wood really had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Matt I don't know -- is assembling plastic fruit in a bowl something that a woodworker is likely to need to do to complete a project? Plexiglas is a material often used in woodworking, and basic information such as how to cut it is certainly relevant to and useful for woodworkers. I'm not sure you can make the same argument about plastic fruit.

Comment: Bad analogy then. This question now exists and was well received so for now this no longer need to be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in an answer for this but I don't how it is on topic with the site. I think DIY would consider it off topic unless your question is expanded to be related to a larger project that would be on topic there.

There is nothing stopping you from asking in chat though....

Answer (score 0):

Within the context of a woodworking project, how to cut plexiglas is a valid question. However, a more general question about how to cut plexiglas on DIY.SE might serve you better because the answers won't be biased toward more woodworking-specific tools.

Answer (score -1):

It's a question about using **woodworking** tools, of course it's on topic.

Maybe the answers expand the use of some rather expensive equipment, or maybe they clue me in that, oops, I better not try that again.

If someone were to propose turning a turnip, I would be quite intrigued and curious about the answers and experiences of our fellow turners.  As a matter of fact, no less a lathe master than Rude Osolnik was known to turn stone on a wood lathe, demonstrating and advocating it in seminars and workshops.

If the context of a question were to be working with non-wood products using a tool normally used for wood in a space that the questioner might normally consider a wood shop I would consider it ON topic. This becomes especially meaningful when the safety aspects of doing so lift there ugly little heads when a different technique might be necessary to complete an operation.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean this exactly but I disagree with the premise as stated. If I use a compass to help with my kids math homework is that on topic? It uses a woodworking tool. What about using my chisel to remove the skin off a turnip. I'm sure that is not on topic. Yes these are extreme examples to prove a point. While I'm sure that it can cut other things (not sure if you should) Table saws at WW are for cutting wood.

Comment: Turning the turnip on a lathe might have been a better example

Comment: Would you argue then that a question about turning stone be on topic?